# Vue 3: How to inject a dependency within another dependency globally using the provide and inject() functions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, dependency-injection

I'm using Vue.js app.provide() and inject() to inject some service dependencies into my application. However, some of these services depend on other services to be built.

I haven't found any way to pass these dependencies by retrieving them from the dependency container itself, as inject() only works in the context of Vue components. This way whenever I try to retrieve a dependency to pass as a parameter I get undefined as a return.

Examples:

```js
// main.ts

export class MyService1 {
    constructor() {}
}

export class MyService2 {
    constructor(readonly myService1: MyService1) {}
}

const app = createApp(App);
app.provide("MyService1", new MyService1());
app.provide("MyService2", new MyService2(inject("MyService1"))); // <-- MyService1 is undefined

app.mount('#app');
```

I even tried using a factory in inject with the treatDefaultAsFactory flag activated but without success, same result.

```js
// main.ts

[...]
app.provide("MyService2", new MyService2(inject("MyService1", () => new MyService1(), true))); // <-- MyService1 is undefined
```

Is there any way to do this using this Vue injection system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It cannot be done this way because provide/inject relies on component hierarchy, `inject` should be called strictly in `setup` function or contemporary lifecycle hooks. Vue DI is hierarchical and injected value can differ depending on a component where it's used. Since it's not the case here, the code can be simplified to:

```
const myService1 = new MyService1();
const myService2 = new MyService2(myService1);

app.provide("myService1", myService1);
app.provide("myService2", myService2);
```

It's possible to use helper function instead of `inject('myService2')`:

```
const injectMyService2 = () => new MyService2(inject('myService1'));
```

But since this code implies that `myService1` and `myService2` are singletons, the helper won't work the same way. Using singletons in in hierarchical manner would require to keep track of service instances and their dependencies in DI container, which is not a job for Vue DI. In more complex scenario third-party hierarchical DI container can be used like `injection-js`, which is Angular DI that was decoupled from the framework.

Comment: Yeah, just to add my thoughts (for the OP), why would you care a bout DI in a context where you instantiate all the services? It would only be relevant if you instantiated a service down the line (where I would recommend the use of a vue composable). Also, the vue provider is a simple as dirt key-value storage so you could just create your own (eg. Map) if you need something like this for an out-of-vue context.

Comment: @GeriDremák provide/inject is useful because of its hierarchical nature, also in the context of multiapp setup each app can get its own instances, something that couldn't be easily achieved with composition api otherwise because a component can't easily access `this`. But yes, in this case it looks like overengineering.